# Using UITableView in UIView with existing TableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, uitableview

I have several `UITableViewController`s. I want to use one of those controllers as delegate and data source for a `UITableView` in some other view. I have an `IBOutlet` in the view controller containing the table view, and it is connected to the table view in IB.

How do I connect the table view to the delegate and datasource (which is a table view controller I already have to display the same content)? I have tried draging a `NSObject` in the black bar below my view controller and setting the class to `MyTableViewController`, connecting the delegate and datasource to this, but it wil crash when the view loads, without a descriptive error.

Will the `viewDidAppear:` on the delegate fire (this is where I fetch the content for the table view)?

I would *really* have liked to post a screenshot, but I am too new.

Comment: I made a nice screenshot to illustrate my intentions, but, as a new user I am not allowed to post images yes... :( sorry!

Comment: Ok so you need two UITableViews in the same UIViewController?

Comment: Nope.. only one. I will clarify my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i connect the TableView to the Delegate and Datasource (Which
>   is a TableViewController I already have to display the same content) ?

```
self.myTableView.dataSource=myTableViewController.table.dataSource;
self.myTableView.delegate=myTableViewController.table.delegate;
```

Can this help?

Edit1: Even if this helps and you find a solution, I am tempted to say you have an architecture problem.

Comment: Tried this to... What's strange is is the following... When i make an empty TableViewController (testTVC), link it and compile.. No problem. When I return not 0 on Nr of sections and NR of cells all goes pearshaped... I wil start an empty project to illustrate my problem and post is...

Comment: Why do you have to use a TableViewController?

Comment: I am under the impression it's the Cocoa-way. I'd love to use [myTableView addCell: myCell]; or something similar, but I think it's not possible?!

Comment: You can simply add a UITableView to a UIViewController and make it compliant to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Started from scratch, seems to be an odd error probably tracable to an architecture problem... Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand it all but a tableviewcontroller does make the assumption that your table fills the screen. So if you're looking at displaying some server specific data with and existing controller and then adding a table view, the best is to use the existing controller as the delegate of the table view. Define an IBOutlet var to the table view to use it when you want to trigger a reload or other non-delegate operations. It is definitely easier to define the outlets and delegates via IB rather than programatically if you're new to the field.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried the way you suggest, but it doesnt seem to work. Let me clarify the original question.